# why thank you page in woocommerce doesn't work properly?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

why the ordered items doesn't appear in my thankyou pages? there is no invoice detail as usual.. i don't know why, now it's only a message only.. several weeks ago, invoice detail appears and can work properly..

i think the error code is at thankyou.php at woocommerce/checkout

i find that variable $order cannot be read, so the if clause is skipped to the else one.. then it only shows the messages in the bottom of codes in thankyou.php (below is the codes)

my goal is to show the invoice detail in my woocommerce thank you pages, not only the messages.

```
<?php
/**
 * Thankyou page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.2.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( $order ) : ?>

<?php if ( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) : ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed"><?php _e( 'Pesaan Anda belum dapat kami proses sehubungan BANK Anda telah menolak transaksi. Silahkan coba melakukan pemesanan ulang.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed-actions">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
        <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'My Account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>

<?php else : ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Terima kasih, Pemesanan Anda baru saja kami terima. Anda juga bisa melihat detail pemesanan melalui email yang kami kirimkan.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>

    <ul class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">
        <li class="order">
            <?php _e( 'Nomor Pesanan:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
        </li>
        <li class="date">
            <?php _e( 'Tanggal Pesan:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></strong>
        </li>
        <li class="total">
            <?php _e( 'Total Bayar:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
        </li>
        <?php if ( $order->payment_method_title ) : ?>
        <li class="method">
            <?php _e( 'Cara Bayar:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
            <strong><?php echo $order->payment_method_title; ?></strong>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->payment_method, $order->id ); ?>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->id ); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Terima kasih. Pemesanan Anda baru saja Kami terima. Detail pemesanan dapat Anda lihat melalui email yang baru saja kami kirimkan. Anda bisa cek email sekarang. Bila tidak menemukan email, silahkan cek folder spam dan pindahkan ke bukan spam.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```